# Rally sandbox queries fail that work on rally1

Tags: sandbox, rally

I have an app that has working WSAPI queries to populate a cardboard and grid (works on rally1.rallydev.com), and it was even working 2 weeks ago in the rally sandbox (sandbox.rallydev.com).  Now, when I run the app in the sandbox environment, I get network errors saying the get requests from sandbox.rallydev.com failed:

```
Failed to load resource
    https://sandbox.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/PortfolioItem...
```

but when I click on the link that failed, it shows the data I requested!

```
{"QueryResult": { "_rallyAPIMajor": "2", ...
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: Via Rally Support:

In templates folder there is App.html, and that's where I commented out parentRepos:

    Rally.launchApp('{{className}}', {
        name:"{{name}}",
        //parentRepos:"{{{parents}}}"
    });

Note: commenting out or deleting this line from App.html under deploy folder does not help because the line gets regenerated from the template(assuming you are using 'grunt deploy' command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error:

```
Uncaught Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String:Failed to load resource
```

may come up if you have

```
parentRepos:"{{{parents}}}"
```

in

```
 Rally.launchApp('{{className}}', {
                name:"{{name}}",
                parentRepos:"{{{parents}}}"
            });
```

in App.html

Please comment it out

Note: commenting out or deleting this line must be done in App.html under templates folder. It does not help if it is done in App.html deploy folder because the line gets regenerated from the template(assuming you are using 'grunt deploy' command).